# Application of the approximation theorem in the proof of Nuekirch's Algebraic Number Theory, (1.9) proposition.

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I'm reading the Neukirch's Algebraic number theory, p.365, (1.9) proposition and I stuck at understanding some statement.

[image]

I'm trying to understand the underlined statement.
Here,

1. The homomorphism is defined in his book p.359.
2. $I_K$ is the idele group of $K$(number field) (his book p.357)
3. $J_K$ is the ideal group of $K$ (his book p.21).
4. $C_K$ is the idele class group (his book p.359)
5. $\mathfrak{m} = \prod_{\mathfrak{p}}\mathfrak{p}^{n_\mathfrak{p}}$ is a module(modulus) of $K$ (his book p.363)
6. $C_K^{\mathfrak{m}}$ is the congruence subgroup mod $\mathfrak{m}$ (his book p363)
7. $Cl^{\mathfrak{m}}_K := J^{\mathfrak{m}}_K / P^{\mathfrak{m}}_K$ is defined in p.365
8. In the proof, $U_{\mathfrak{p}}^{(n_{\mathfrak{p}})}$ is defined as p.363.

How can we apply the approximation theorem to find such $a \in K^{*}$? Here, the approximation theorem means (his book p.117, (3.4) Theorem)

> (3.4) Approximation Theorem. Let $| \ |_1, \cdots ,| \ |_n$ be pairwise inequivalent valuations of the field $K$ and let $a_1, \cdots , a_n \in K$ be given elements. Then for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists an $x\in K$ such that
> $$ |x-a_i|_i <\epsilon $$ for all $i=1, \cdots , n.$

An issue that makes me somewhat annoying is how to set $a_1, \cdots , a_n \in K$ in the approximation theorem to apply. In the proof, each $\alpha_{\mathfrak{p}}$ is in $K_\mathfrak{p}^{*}$, not in $K$..

Comment: Look on page 193 for another approximation theorem.

Comment: O.K. I'll refer to it.~